# How to place controls depending on there data in ios?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am facing an issue with statically placing controls on view in viewcontroller, i am using storyboard for designing all the UI flow in an app using autolayout, among few viewcontrollers, one of them will be getting data from the server, i had statically placed all the controls, and it looks good if i am getting data for all the controls in that viewcontroller.There are  also chances that few controls may not have data, if few controls doesn't have data, then the space for that perticular control is left empty and looks bad. i need to remove that control if there is no data for that and had to move other controls so that there is no empty space left. is placing controls dynamically is only the option for this? or can i achieve this applying constraints for each control using autolayout? any sample or link would help me a lot. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry there are no such options for this using storyboard (or xib). You have to approach your problem using code only.